# Display content based on selected checkbox value

Tags: python, django

I am trying to retrieve the information based on the selected checkbox value. Right now, i have managed to display the content accordingly based on the selected checkbox. However, it only works for one selected checkbox. If i select more than 1 checkbox, it will return the last selected checkbox.

I understand I have to use request.POST.getlist('name') to pass multiple checkbox value. When I did this, it displays nothing.

I would like to show the name of students who have attended the class on the selected week.

Below is my sample code:

Views.py

```
    def filterWeek(request):


        qs = MarkAtt.objects.all()

        week_checked = request.GET.get('week_check')

        if week_checked:
            # week_mchecked = request.POST.getlist('week_check') #not working, display nothing
#qs = qs.filter(week_in=week_mchecked)
            qs = qs.filter(week=week_checked)

        context={
        'queryset' : qs
        }
        return render(request, "filter.html", context)
```

Templates:

```
       <form method="GET" action=".">


 <input type="checkbox" id="week_check" name="week_check" value="1"/> Week 1

 <input type="checkbox" id="week_check" name="week_check" value="2"/> Week 2

<input type="checkbox" id="week_check" name="week_check" value="3"/> Week 3

</form>
```

Hope anyone of u could help me out. Appreciate it so much.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried to change this:

```
  week_mchecked = request.POST.getlist('week_check')
```

to

```
week_mchecked = request.GET.getlist('week_check')
```

and it is working. Apparently, i just realised my form method is GET and not POST.